# Can I change the tag info/topic if the tag is used for a different topic than stated in the tag info?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

According to the tag info is the tag [neat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neat) intended for discussions about thoughtbot's *Neat* framework (a semantic grid framework built on top of Sass and Bourbon). This project is no longer maintained.

The tag however is mainly used for discussion about the 'Neuroevolution of Augmenting Topologies' algorithm, also called *NEAT*. 20 out of the 21 questions tagged with [neat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neat) that were asked in 2020 were about the NEAT algorithm and not the Neat semantic grid framework. The one question tagged with [neat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neat) but not about the NEAT algorithm was about a topic that had nothing to do with either the *NEAT* algorithm or the *Neat* semantic grid framework.

I would therefore like to repurpose the tag [neat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neat) to be about the 'Neuroevolution of Augmenting Topologies' algorithm instead of the *Neat* semantic grid framework by thoughtbot. Am I even allowed to do that and if so, what is the correct procedure of doing so? Is there a plenum that allows for a veto when changing the topic of a tag or should I simply edit the tag info and let it be approved by someone with more reputation?

Comment: The correct procedure would be to edit the tag info, and to close questions (if they are closable) that aren't about the purpose we assigned them. But first people have to agree with your proposal.

Comment: And I find out if people agree with my proposal in this question thread or do I have to create some separate proposal?

Comment: No need for that. This is where people will post answers saying whether or not they agree.

Comment: Should the upvotes on this question also be interpreted as "I agree"?

Comment: Is it possible to (easily) change the `neat` tag to `neat-framework`?

Comment: @KalindaPride "Should the upvotes on this question also be interpreted as "I agree"?" In this case rather not. Voting on Meta on questions is difficult to interpret because people could vote for various reasons. On answers it's more clear and the highest voted answers says rather no, so people kind of disagree. They still seem to like the question though. Maybe they appreciate the effort.

Comment: @Trilarion, just to clarify: The highest voted answer at the moment (by @IlmariKaronen) doesn't say no in the sense that they disagree with my question. It says that the tag definitely should be changed but by splitting the [tag:neat] tag into seperate tags. The upvotes to my question indicate agreement on the underlying issue, not just appreciation of the effort.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think changing the meaning of the existing tag is a good idea, because we already have a lot of questions about the original meaning.

In particular, out of the 281 total questions currently tagged with [neat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neat), [175 are also tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neat+bourbon) with [bourbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bourbon) and [104 are also tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neat+bourbon) with [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass).  Adding those together and subtracting the [85 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neat+sass+bourbon) tagged with all three tags, we get a total of 194 questions that are definitely about the semantic grid framework, i.e.about 69% of the total.  And my search probably missed some questions that are about the grid framework but didn't happen to be tagged with either [bourbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bourbon) or [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass).

That said, the tag certainly should be disambiguated somehow.  One option might be to rename the current tag to something like [neat-sass-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neat-sass-grid), and create a new tag such as [neat-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neat-algorithm) for the NEAT algorithm.

Then someone would need to go through the renamed old tag and retag any mistagged questions about the NEAT algorithm with the new tag.  While somewhat laborious, that's still less work than retagging all old questions about the grid framework.

(Renaming the old tag requires ♦ moderator assistance, but if there seems to be a consensus for it, the new [neat-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neat-algorithm) tag could certainly be created and applicable questions retagged by community members even while the rename request is pending.)

Comment: Thank you for your input Ilmari, those are certainly very valid points and ideas you brought up and I think you made a good case for your approach. Now, as someone unfamiliar with the procedure do I have to ask again how to proceed!? Will we choose the approach depending on which answer gets more upvotes? As you said does it also seem that moderator assistance is required if historically splitting the tag. Probably worth to clarify first if such a moderator is available for that task considering the small size of that tag...!?

Comment: @PaulOnStackoverflow No need for any new questions related to this. You currently have two answers, with two different proposed solutions.  Give your question some time (typically a week or more), then see which proposal (if any) seems to get a consensus. There might also be other possible solutions that get added as other answers.

Comment: [tag:neat-sass-grid] is a horrible name for the tag, FWIW. Just create a [tag:neat-algorithm] tag and start retagging the ones about that to use this new tag.

Comment: @TylerH: Better suggestions welcome. I do maintain, however, that [tag:neat] on its own should not be a tag, since it's clearly ambiguous and used for several different things.

Comment: I very much second that [tag:neat] shouldn't be a tag on its own as it is too ambiguous. I often untag the [tag:neat] tag from questions that have nothing to do with the sass grid or the neuroevolution algorithm, but by far most often the tag is misused for the NE algorithm - hence why opened this issue.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The tag should be renamed to [tag:bourbon-neat] since that's the [actual name of the framework](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/introducing-bourbon-neat-a-sass-based-responsive-grid).

Comment: @TylerH: I think they may have changed the branding with version 2.0; the [website](https://neat.bourbon.io/) hasn't called it "Bourbon Neat" since [May 3, 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170503204925/http://neat.bourbon.io/). But the [npm package](https://npm.io/package/bourbon-neat) is still called "bourbon-neat" (even if the [Ruby gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/neat) is just "neat"), so I guess the name could still be appropriate.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Even if the name changed, it still relies on bourbon. If it's horribly objectionable then we can just go with [tag:neat-framework].

Comment: After 10 days and no further activity in the thread have I accepted your solution and requested moderator assistance in order to rename the tags. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -6):

> 20 out of the 21 questions tagged with neat that were asked in 2020 were about the NEAT algorithm and not the Neat semantic grid framework. The one question tagged with neat but not about the NEAT algorithm was about a topic that had nothing to do with either...

This seems like a clear case for changing the tag topic. The old tag topic is useless (no questions with the tag match that topic), but the new tag topic would be useful, because it would immediately apply to 20 related questions.

Good work!

Comment: Note that the tag is currently used on a total of 281 questions. [At a glance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bneat%5D+sass), the overwhelming majority of those questions seem to be about the SASS based framework.